# Does rollback only work on our own edits?

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks

I'm asking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960320/list-index-out-of-range-whenever-i-change-the-list-size) post specifically. Whether it was on purpose or not, the OP deleted the code only (sounds kind of suspicious).

I went into the edit log and wanted to rollback to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32960320/6) edit by [Hayley Guillou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3223917/hayley-guillou) as it was helpful.

But I get the message saying `Unable to rollback to the current revision`.

Is that because the edit isn't my own? I do not want to rollback to mine because she added a visualization that's worth keeping. I even left a comment and no answer from OP.

Why can't we rollback to someone else's edit?

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being a different user. Looks like there's some sort of bug with the rollback functionality when you try to rollback to a revision created from a suggested edit.

Comment: @animuson: You cannot roll back to an approved edit suggestion that was improved upon, presumably because the improvement is part of the outcome of the edit suggestion. See the immediately following revision. I think you should be able to do this, because sometimes an "improvement" really isn't.

Comment: This raises the question, if suggested edits are not "real" edits, why do they appear in the edit history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the code was that it was identifying the "current revision" by looking for the revision with the newest timestamp. Since edit suggestions have their timestamp set to the time of the suggestion's acceptance (which means the time of the improvement, if the acceptor decided to improve the post), it gets selected as the current revision.

I've fixed this by tie-breaking with the revision number. This will go out in build 3746 for MSE/MSO, and build 2869 for other sites.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.